# Can't find `ref` using findDOMNode() after componentDidMount() in this simple example

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Does anyone understand why I can't get reference `foo` with `findDOMNode` and `this.refs.foo` in the following example? As far as I know `foo` should be available after `componentDidMount`? What can I do to make this right? (I'm using React 15.2.1)

```
class PageComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <WrapperComp>
          <div ref="foo">item</div>
          <div>item</div>
        </WrapperComp>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

class WrapperComp extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const tryNode1 = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.foo);
    const tryNode2 = this.refs.foo;
    console.log(tryNode1);
    console.log(tryNode2);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.props.children }
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <PageComp />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/vameho/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: I suppose that you can't get `refs` from other components, it is break encapsulation. You can pass it as props.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Alexander T's comment is correct.

Also, the recommended way of accessing DOM elements is by using callback refs. (Read the "Note" in red here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute)

E.g. to take your `PageComp` component:

```
class PageComp extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
     // use this.foo here at will
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <WrapperComp>
          <div ref={(el) => this.foo = el}>item</div>
          <div>item</div>
        </WrapperComp>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Which will set `this.foo` to be that element, without using `findDOMNode`

Comment: Ouch, `(el) => this.foo = el` seems nasty. A lot of linters will warn you for making an arrow function with a side effect

Comment: This suggestion comes from the React documentation, and also Dan Abramov advocates it: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678

Comment: Sure, I know it's from the docs, but it still feels "wrong" to me.

Comment: this.setRef.bind(this) can be used if the arrow function feels "wrong", setRef must be defined on the class of course

Answer (score 1):

`this.refs.foo` returns React Element. But if you want to work with DOM element - you need to find this Node

React 15.0.1 Requires this syntax: `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.foo)`

Hope the issue is coming in tryNode2?

Also you have move the below block, under `class PageComp extends React.Component {`

`componentDidMount() {
    const tryNode1 = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.foo);
    const tryNode2 = this.refs.foo;
    console.log(tryNode1);
    console.log(tryNode2);
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.refs` to find DOM markup rendered by a component. You are using `this.refs` in another component

[**DOCS**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)